# passing dynamically declared array as constant in c++

Tags: c++

I dynamically created an array using a function like this:

```
//..
    double ** allocate_2d(const int wd1, const int wd2){
    double **array = new double*[wd1];

    for(int idx=0; idx<wd1; idx++)
    {
        array[idx] = new double[wd2];
    }

    return array;
}
```

I would like to pass the resulting array into a function as a constant parameter. I want the array to be "read only" within the function.

```
func(const double ** array)
{
    // computations using array
}
```

However I get the following error:
 `invalid conversion from ‘double**’ to ‘const double**’`

Is it possible to do something like this?

Comment: In C++ whenever you think of "dynamic array", your next thought should almost always be `std::vector`. Using `std::vector` you would not have the problem you have now (which I know there are duplicates of, even though I can't seem to find it).

Comment: Thank you. I will try that. I would still like to understand what it doesn't work.

Comment: And, in C++, if you care about performance and efficiency (which is usually why one chooses C++), whenever you think about "multi-dimensional array", your next thought should be storing its elements in a one-dimensional array ;).

Comment: See http://c-faq.com/ansi/constmismatch.html for why this isn't allowed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why OP's signature

```
func(const double ** array){
    // computations using array
}
```

generates an error when a `double **` is passed as an argument, lies in the rules of qualification conversions.

Quoting https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion (emphasis mine):

> **Qualification conversions**
>
> - A [prvalue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#prvalue) of type pointer to [cv-qualified](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv) type T can be converted to a prvalue pointer to a **more** cv-qualified same type T (in other words, constness and volatility can be added).
> - [...]
>
> "More" cv-qualified means that
>
> - a pointer to unqualified type can be converted to a pointer to const;
> - [...]
>
> For multi-level pointers, the following restrictions apply: a multilevel pointer P1 which is *cv*<sup>*1*</sup><sub>*0*</sub>-qualified pointer to *cv*<sup>*1*</sup><sub>*1*</sub>-qualified pointer to ... *cv*<sup>*1*</sup><sub>*n-1*</sub>-qualified pointer to *cv*<sup>*1*</sup><sub>*n*</sub>-qualified T is convertible to a multilevel pointer P2 which is *cv*<sup>*2*</sup><sub>*0*</sub>-qualified pointer to *cv*<sup>*2*</sup><sub>*1*</sub>-qualified pointer to ... *cv*<sup>*2*</sup><sub>*n-1*</sub>-qualified pointer to *cv*<sup>*2*</sup><sub>*n*</sub>-qualified T only if
>
> - the number of levels n is the same for both pointers;
> - if there is a const in the *cv*<sup>*1*</sup><sub>*k*</sub> qualification at some level (other than level zero) of P1, there is a const in the same level *cv*<sup>*2*</sup><sub>*k*</sub> of P2;
> - [...]
> - **if at some level k the P2 is more cv-qualified than P1, then there must be a const at every single level (other than level zero) of P2 up until k**: *cv*<sup>*2*</sup><sub>*1*</sub>, *cv*<sup>*2*</sup><sub>*2*</sub> ... *cv*<sup>*2*</sup><sub>*k*</sub>.
> - [...]
> - level zero is addressed by the rules for non-multilevel qualification conversions.
>
> ```
> char** p = 0;
> const char** p1 = p; // error: level 2 more cv-qualified but level 1 is not const
> const char* const * p2 = p; // OK: level 2 more cv-qualified and 
>                             //     const added at level 1
> ```
>
> Note that in the C programming language, const/volatile can be added to the first level only:
>
> ```
> char** p = 0;
> char * const* p1 = p; // OK in C and C++
> const char* const * p2 = p; // error in C, OK in C++
> ```

So, to enforce constness, the signature needs to be changed into

```
void func(double const * const * array) {
    // ...               ^^^^^ 
}
```

That said, I strongly suggest to change the overall design and avoid that dynamically allocated jagged array, if possible.

Comment: You should try to explain why OP's original attempt at `const double ** array` doesn't work.

Answer (score -2):

You can use `const_cast` to add constness to an object (explicit cast is needed).

```
double **p = allocate_2d(100,200);

// populate p

func(const_cast<const double**>(p));//array pointed by p will be read only inside func
```

Still, you need to consider whether you need `const` there at all.

Comment: No, the solution is to make the `func` definition correct.

Comment: No, people definitely don't do that. If you want to convey that a function doesn't modify a parameter, than mark the parameter as `const` so that the compiler prevents modification, and ensures the correct type is passed through.

Comment: @Mark Ingram, yes, that might be the right solution. People do, however, sometimes use `const` to let other people know that an object is not changed in the function

Comment: @Mark Ingram, I meant to say that the function doesn't modify an object, not an argument  (which I corrected in my comment)

Comment: @dsp_user The const behind a method of a class is unrelated to this question.

Comment: @Bernhard, I never mentioned a class anywhere. What exactly do you mean?

Comment: @dsp_user I think I just don't understand what you mean then.